# In SwiftUI how can I animate view changes when the view that should animate is within a .sheet that is in an overlay of View that contains a List?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm not able to animate view changes when the view that should animate is within a `.sheet` that is in an overlay of View a that contains a `List`. I would appreciate any suggestions

In this example I add an item by opening the sheet on the first tab and tapping the + icon, and then changing the value Textfield to be empty. The "You entered text" `Text` view properly animates, sliding in. I then close the sheet, switch to the second tab, open the sheet, and remove the Text value. The `Text` view incorrectly doesn't animate - it abruptly appears.

This test app depends on a core data model with a single Entity named `Item` with a single `String` attributed called `name` with a default value of an empty string (screenshot attached). I have tested this on an iPhone 15 iOS 17.2 simulator and device.

I am fairly certain all the code is necessary to show a working example side by side with a non working example with only the small change in the contents of the sheets parent view.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ItemEditor: View {
    @ObservedObject var item : Item
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            if let name : Binding<String> = Binding($item.name) {
                TextField("Value", text: name)
            }
            
            ZStack {
                if item.name?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
                    Text("Animated")
                        .transition(.slide)
                }
            }
            .animation(.default, value: item.name)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemOp: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ContentViewWorks()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("1")
                }
            ContentViewDoesntWork()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("2")
                }
        }
    }
}
        
struct ContentViewWorks: View {
    @State var itemOp : ItemOp? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    Button("Show sheet") {
                        itemOp = ItemOp()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            EmptyView()
                .sheet(item: $itemOp) { _ in
                    ContentViewWorksSheet()
                }
        )
    }
}

struct ContentViewWorksSheet: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        ItemEditor(item:item)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.name = ""

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemOp2: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var item : Item
}
        
struct ContentViewDoesntWork: View {
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    @State var itemOp : ItemOp2? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Button("Show sheet") {
                        itemOp = ItemOp2(item: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            EmptyView()
                .sheet(item: $itemOp) { item in
                    ContentViewDoesntWorkInner(item: item.item)
                }
        )
    }
}

struct ContentViewDoesntWorkInner: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @ObservedObject var item : Item

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    ItemEditor(item:item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@main
struct TestCoreDataAnimApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestCoreDataAnim")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}
```

[image: core data model]

Comment: Are you sure *all* that code is necessary to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I am fairly certain all the code is necessary to show a working example side by side with a non working example with only the small change in the contents of the sheets parent view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of issues that I found. The first had to do with the viewContext not getting saved in between the changes in the sheet. The reason I think this is that the problem shows up even if you just have two ContentViewWorks() in the tabview. Saving the context on disappearance of the sheet fixed this part of the issue for me.

However, after fixing that, the animation problem was still present for the ContentViewDoesntWork(). I am not sure why you have the problem still in the view. I tried saving the item every time the name changed, and that animated the text leaving but not coming into the view. (Which is too many saves to leave in the app, I am just saying this as a clue for someone else that may know more about the problem than I).

The thing that ultimately worked was making the animation depend on something other than the name. I made a private state variable that was set without animation on appear and then with animation whenever the name changed from empty to non-empty. My best guess is that there was something that was causing the UI to be redrawn in a way that bypassed the animation (or cut off the animation while it was happening).

Here is the full code of my working version:

```
struct ItemEditor: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var item : Item
    
    @State private var showAnimated: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            if let name : Binding<String> = Binding($item.name) {
                TextField("Value", text: name)
            }
            
            if showAnimated {
                Text("Animated")
                    .transition(.slide)
                    
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            showAnimated = !(item.name?.isEmpty ?? true)
        }
        .onChange(of: item.name) {
            withAnimation(.default) {
                showAnimated = !(item.name?.isEmpty ?? true)
            }
            //save() This only animated on disappearance I left this here for paragraph 2 of the explanation.
        }
    }
//    func save() {
//        do {
//            try item.managedObjectContext?.save()
//        } catch let error {
//            print(error)
//        }
//    }
    
}



struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ContentViewWorks()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("1")
                }
            
            ContentViewDoesntWork()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("2")
                }
            
        }
    }
}

struct ItemOp: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
}
struct ItemOp2: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var item : Item
}

struct ContentViewWorks: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var itemOp : ItemOp? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    Button("Show sheet") {
                        itemOp = ItemOp()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $itemOp) { _ in
            ContentViewWorksSheet()
                .onDisappear {
                    save()
                }
            
        }
        
    }
    func save() {
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentViewDoesntWork: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    @State var itemOp : ItemOp2?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    Button("\(item.name ?? "")") {
                        itemOp = ItemOp2(item: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $itemOp) { item in
            ContentViewDoesntWorkInner(item: item.item)
        }
        
    }
    func save() {
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentViewWorksSheet: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        ItemEditor(item:item)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.name = ""
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentViewDoesntWorkInner: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @ObservedObject var item : Item
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    ItemEditor(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
    
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestCoreDataAnim")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}

@main
struct TestCoreDataAnimApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

I am sorry I do not fully understand why it wasn't working earlier, but this does make the animation work now.

Comment: Thank you. This answer does work in the example. When I added the code to my real app I found that the animation only plays about 50% of the time that it should.

Comment: I am sorry that it doesn't quite work for your case. Are there other values that are getting changed at the same time as the name? Without seeing your code, my guess is that there is some other state changing that is causing a race condition in the view updates. Do you have any other clues to get it fixed in yours?

Comment: Thank you for asking. Do you have any pointers on how to figure out what might be causing the issue? There dont seem to be any debugging or tracing tools for animations.

Comment: Here is an article that is helpful. One of the things that it talks about is that Swift provides us with a private static method Self._printChanges() that prints out the trigger of a redraw. I would recommend wrapping that in an #if DEBUG statement because it can impact performance pretty significantly, and so should never be included in production. https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/debugging-swiftui-views/